# The function to get the DataRow field or the default value

Tags: c#, extension-methods, datarow

I have an old code that defines the following utility function

```
string kod_custno_billto = DbUtil.RowStringValue(row, "kod_custno_billto", "");
```

Where the `row` is of the `DataRow` type, and the third parameter is the wanted default value if the `NULL` is in the database. It is implemented like that:

```
static public string RowStringValue(DataRow row, string column_name, string default_value)
{
    string result = default_value;
    if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(column_name) && !Convert.IsDBNull(row[column_name]))
        result = Convert.ToString(row[column_name]);
    return result;
}
```

I was thinking about using the existing `DataRowExtensions.Field`, like this:

```
string kod_custno_billto = row.Field<string>("kod_custno_billto");
```

The missing functionality for mass replacement of the older code is the default value instead of the returned `null`. How would you implement that?

Comment: @dymanoid Yes, I was thinking about it. But I am not very fluent in C#. I would be able to create the extension function from that one. However, there is a set of such functions, based on the wanted output type. For that I need the templated extension. Moreover, it could be the case that something like that was already implemented or is simple (and I only cannot see what is obvious).

Comment: Could be the `row.Field<string>("kod_custno_billto") ?? my_default;` be the wanted solution?

Comment: `row.Field<string>("kod_custno_billto") ?? my_default;` null-coalescing would do the trick, unless if there are other cases that have not been covered in your question.